# SplitApp on portrait mode. Show 1st view instead of the 2nd view

Tags: sapui5

On UI5 and FIORI SplitApp application, whenever users are viewing the app on portrait mode on their devices, the first screen that is being shown is the 2nd view/screen. Is it possible to bypass this behavior (but still using splitapp) so the on load of the application, users will see the 1st screen of the split app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your targets in your `manifest.json` (or wherever you are defining your `routes`)

```
"routes": [{
    "pattern": "",
    "name": "master",
    "target": ["home", "master"]
}, {
    ...
}]
```

This means that `home` (the detail view) is rendered below `master` (the master view), thus the master view is shown first.