# Display MasterView on default SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to make a fiori app using `<SplitApp>` view. My problem is when I use small device such as phone (portrait mode), the master view is not shown, but only the detail view (look like below):
[image: This is the detail view]

I've tried to use property `mode="PopoverMode"` or `StretchCompressMode` but none of those worked. 
Any suggestion? 
Thanks and Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SplitApp on portrait mode. Show 1st view instead of the 2nd view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374619/splitapp-on-portrait-mode-show-1st-view-instead-of-the-2nd-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I change the order of 2 views in target from:`[master, detail]` to `[detail, master]`

Answer (score 0):

[`SplitApp`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitApp.html) is another root element of a UI5 mobile application besides App control.
It maintains **two NavContainers if running on tablet/desktop** and **one - on phone**. The display of master NavContainer depends on the portrait/landscape mode of the device and the mode of SplitApp.

Try to add items to the master page and then navigate and check if it goes to detail screen.